# Wagtail Image Chooser Template returns 404 http not found

Tags: django, nginx, wagtail, wagtail-admin, wagtail-snippet

When I deploy my wagtail django with nginx and I want to choose an image for a ForeignKeyField to `wagtailimages.Image` I get a HTTP 404 for
`<base-url>/cms/images/chooser/` although when I directly access the url it returns the correct json.

Is this a nginx Problem or a wagtail / django problem?